# GSP files do not open in intellij editor community edition

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I copied my grails app to another computer and now .gsp files do not open in the editor. They also show a G icon with an arrow next to them. Dragging and dropping or double clicking do nothing. Updating intellij didn't help either

[image: icon next to gsp files]

Comment: Are you using the community or ultimate edition of IntelliJ?

Comment: Community, but only for editing I run the grails app from the command line

Comment: The community edition of IntelliJ doesn't include Grails support, so I wouldn't expect GSPs to be recognised.

Comment: gsps open fine on 2 other computers. That is not the answer to why they wont open

Comment: You can use GGTS IDE built on top of eclipse for Grails development.

Comment: You can use GGTS IDE built on top of eclipse for Grails development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installing community version fixed and gsp files now open in the editor

Comment: I think you may have installed a plugin for that file type.  That's what I did and the `.gsp` files stopped opening.

Answer (score 2):

As [Dónal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648/d%C3%B3nal) mentioned, Grails is not one of the frameworks supported by IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (you need the Ultimate Edition).  You can view the feature comparison [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Comment: I don't use IntelliJ so I don't really know how it works.  I know that the Grails support is only in the Ultimate Edition but the OP says that the GSP won't even open in an editor.  Is it really the case that you can't even edit the file in Community Edition?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it should at least open the gsp files even as plain text without the coloring.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am probably answering now when u no longer need the answer but I bumped into the same issue yesterday and only solved it now. There are chances that you associated the .gsp file type with a program which cannot be opened by intellij in your case GOSU. To fix it go to: File>Settings>Editor>File Types
In the file types go to Gosu Program Source and *.gsp should be in the registered patterns. Remove it and apply changes then you are good to go.